# Logging in to website accounts using HTTP requests, e-mail and password

Tags: authentication, http, google-signin

Suppose I have an account created on a website (in specific, a PS Network account or Google account), and I only know the login email, but not the password (with no access to the Google account in the PSN case).
Is there a way for me to verify if a given password is the correct one using only HTTP requests or something similar using code? This is to save me the time of trying multiple passwords and having to wait for a server response until I find the right one.

Details:
I'm not trying to hack into someone's account.
I tried to log in to a secondary PSN account I created years ago but I didn't know the password, only the email (I also created a specific google account/email for this purpose, so I don't remember its password either). Even though I don't remember the exact password, I know which combinations of specific words and numbers I might have used back then. But I want to run through "all" the possible combinations with code, instead of doing it manually, to save time and effort. Is there any URL to which I can make POST requests to try and log in using only email and password in the request body, and verify if login was successful? (either on PSN or Google, either one will give me my PSN account back)

Thanks in advance

I tried looking for REST API and URLs that allow me to do this, but it seems to me that Google in specific has gone strict on this, requiring more than just address and password. For the PSN account, I tried to sniff around using developer tools to watch which URLs are requested when I try to login using the Sony website interface, but I can't understand which requests are doing what.

Comment: Any system that has some moderate requirements will have a way to prevent you from doing this, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a popular method for hacking account access.   it is called bruit force where by the hacker you continues to try passwords over and over again until they gain access.   A dictionary file is often used containing `combinations of specific words and numbers`

No system is going to have an endpoint that will make it easier for hackers to gain access to user accounts by force.

May I suggest using a reset password account recovery option available through most login services these days.

instead of trying to bruit force your way in.  Most authorization servers will lock an account after 5 bad attempts.

Comment: I have no access to either the PSN account nor the Google one, and recovery wasn't set up on any of them, so recovery is out of the question.
This  is why I think brute forcing is the only way.

Back to HTTP requests, login has to be made using some combination of these, right? So it must only be a matter of finding which endpoints need to be used and with which payloads, right? (this is more of a theoretical question than practical, at this point I just want to know if its possible)